# Dropdown menu on Link button?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I have created user control for menu bar and loading in Master page. User control  has Link buttons. Now I want create drop down menu for one of Link buttons. I dont know, how to do that? Is there any other control that supports?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAttributeProcessing"  CausesValidation="False" ForeColor="White" runat="server">Data Processing</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lbLinks" ForeColor="White" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnGroupsetup" CausesValidation="False" ForeColor="White" runat="server">Group Set-up</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegressionConfiguration" CausesValidation="False" ForeColor="White"
                                runat="server">Regression Configuration</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblConvPipe" ForeColor="White" runat="server">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp </asp:Label>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDetailedGroupConfig" CausesValidation="False" ForeColor="White"
                                runat="server">Detailed Group Config</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Why LinkButton ? It's more make sense using Hyperlink .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest route to take is the [asp:Menu control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.aspx). You can replace your `asp:LinkButton` controls with `asp:MenuItem` elements.

If you want a simple client-side solution (your question is tagged "jquery", so I suspect this is on the radar), you could put your sub-menus in `<div>` tags and then use the [jQuery hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function to show and hide the sub-menu `<div>` when the appropriate parent item is hovered.

If you have more than one or two sub-menus, you might investigate a full jQuery drop-down menu plug-in:

- [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)
- [Simple Dropdowns](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/#)